# Continuous variable portfolio optimization problem

Tags: qiskit, optimization

Has anyone tried to solve the continuous variable portfolio optimization in Qiskit? I see a lot of binary variable problems but none which solve and get the optimal weights.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. The problem is that quantum computers are currently unable to solve continuous optimization, hence a problem has to be binarized. I discussed this in my article https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.01909.

Comment: Also classical computers are usually very good in continuous variable optimizations. Discrete variable optimizations tend to be much harder and where a quantum computer could be of help.